# Example of the grails cucumber plugin?

Tags: grails, cucumber

I want to start using cucumber with my grails project, and this plugin seems like it's still healthily vibrant:

http://grails.org/plugin/cucumber

However, I am completely lost as to how to start.  Are there any tutorials or example grails (2.0 would be awesome) projects which use this cucumber plugin?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a great tutorial by the author:

https://github.com/hauner/grails-cucumber/wiki/Testing-Grails-with-Cucumber-and-Geb